# Как отредактировать обработку информации в коде PYTHON

Tags: python

Вопрос в следующем: как сделать так, чтобы значения из файла заносились и обрабатывались последовательно.

Мне объяснили это так: "Нет возможности взять всю информацию. Нужно обрабатывать информацию "на проходе". Максимум, что можно - формировать ограниченный буфер, Но после его обработки он очищается и обрабатывается следующая часть информации. "

код выполняет следующую задачу : Написать программу, которая читая последовательность чисел из файла, выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию (в числах и символах) с которой она началась.

```
 
start_time = time.time()
symbol_len = 1  # Размер буфера чтения
with open('111.txt','r+') as file:
    a = str(file.read())
    s = re.sub('[^\d]', '', a)
if  os.stat("111.txt").st_size == 0 :
    print("Файл пуст   !!!")
else:
    print("Введена последовоательность :",s)
    res = ''
    res_list = []
    i = 0
 
    while i < len(s):
        if res == '' or (int(res[-1]) < int(s[i])):
            res += s[i]
        else:
            res_list.append(res)
            res = s[i]
        i += 1
 
    res_list.append(res)
    _max = max(res_list, key=len)
    print(f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {_max}\nсимволов - {len(_max)}\nначальный индекс - {s.find(_max)}')
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in Mbytes
    print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Берите построчно и обрабатывайте, храните нужную (!) информацию только по самой длинной последовательности, как получили новую самую длиннную - затирайте старую.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос,но как примерно это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Встречный глупый вопрос: вы код сами писали?

Comment: Да,но только засел за python, мне 12 и делаю лабы брата , но попробую разобраться сам 
думаю вариант ниже подойдёт  

a = file1.readline()
a = str(file.read())
    s = re.sub('[^\d]', '', a)


    if not a:
        break

```

Comment: Да, разбирайтесь и тестируйте. Не мне же в чужом коде разбираться:-) А 12 лет - прекрасный возраст для развития аналитического мышления. Бобби Фишер в 15 стал гроссмейстером.